# xamarin installtion : android new application error

Tags: xamarin

I have just installed xamarin in VS2012 and when I try to create a new android project, using the xamarin template, I get the following error:
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object" and a "project creation failed" indication on the bottom line of the VS IDE

Comment: Are you wanting to use Xamarin as part of a Visual Studio, MSDN subscription or Community?  Or are you a paying Xamarin customer?

Comment: part of visual studio

Comment: In order to use Xamarin as part of your Visual Studio subscription you'll need to be running Visual Studio 2013 or above.  I would recommend updating your tooling and let me know how you get on there.